# Select all matching text in Vim?

Tags: vim, regex

I have a bunch of data, and I want to yank everything that matches the following regex to a register :

```
/'user': '[a-Z]*'
```

Is there any way to copy all the matches to a register in vanilla vim? I've looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/224865/vim-select-text-highlighted-by-search), but it only works for one result, after pressing 'n' to go to the next result, it will use '//e' again and go to the end of the next result, instead of the beginning.

I've also looked at [this SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/608170/vim-yank-multiple-non-continous-chunks-of-text-into-a-registers). It's almost exactly what I'm looking for, except I can't figure out how to change it to work with particular matches instead of the lines they are on.

Comment: Is there ever more than one match per line?

Comment: Yes, multiple matches per line

Answer (score 10):

This can be simply achieved, by running a `:s` command with the `n` flag set (which basically says, to not replace anything (but by using an `\=` in the replace part, you can still capture the matches (see `:h sub-replace-special`). So first let's clear register A:

```
qaq
```

Then you can capture your maches into register a by using:

```
:%s/'user': '[a-Z]*'/\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'V')/gn
```

And paste your matches:

```
:put A
```

This needs at least Vim 7.4 (I forgot the actual patch number).

Comment: This puts each match on its own line, which is useful behavior most of the time. Being a single ex-mode command, it'll also be faster than my macro for really large files. +1.

Comment: Well, you can of course capture it in a list and then later do whatever you want with that. That was just an example since the OP did want to capture it in a register.

Comment: I think this needs to be changed to `[a-zA-Z]`, at least on vim 8.1, otherwise vim says something about reverse character in range.

Comment: @TankorSmash this might depend on the locale

Answer (score 2):

" clear the 'a' register

`qaq`

" global search and yank all lines ('A') into the 'a' register.

`:g/'user': '[a-Z]*'/y A`

Modify the part between `:g/ and /y A` as needed.

" paste into another file

`"aP`

Comment: The data is all on one line

Comment: There should be one line per line found.  If there are multiple instances of the found string per line, then both will be listed in the same output line.

Comment: I mean, the text, all the data, is just one line, wouldnt this just yank that one line?

Comment: Yes, I did not know your data was one long line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:YankMatches` command from my [ExtractMatches plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4795):

```
:%YankMatches /'user': '[a-Z]*'/
```

Each match is put on a new line by default; to use another separator, there's an alternative form.

Comment: Does this plugin really works? A lot of [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74v5Z.png) with the command `%YankMatches /re.sub([^)]*)/`

Comment: @hhh: You also need to install my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433). It's listed as a DEPENDENCY in the plugin's INSTALLATION section.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way (these are inefficient if we're talking about a really large number of entries -- it should be fine so long as we're not talking thousands and thousands), but the first thing that comes to mind is a recursive macro. First, turn of the wrapscan option so that searches that reach the end of the file won't loop around to the beginning again (otherwise you'll end up with an infinite loop):

```
:set nowrapscan
```

Then, make sure you have two clear registers:

```
qqq
qaq
```

Now, the magic:

```
qq/'user': '[a-Z]*'
"Ay//e
@qq
```

`qq` starts recording all your keystrokes to the register `q`. Using a capital letter makes vim append to that register rather than overwriting it. `y//e` yanks to the end of your search.  `@q` calls the (currently-empty) `q` register as a macro, and the final `q` stops the recording. Then, simply:

```
@q
```